# Removing links - Pintrest & Adobe Spark

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-format

I know Spark is an online tool so I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, so I apologize in advance if I'm in the wrong place.

I'm sure there's a way I create a mood board on AdobeSpark from a Pinterest board, but I'm not sure how. I'd like the end result to be a mood board of images but without the links underneath. Am open to any other methods outside of Spark.

I'm aware I can save all the images from the boards but for the amount, I have to do just know this would be quite time-consuming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a browser plugin. Pretty sure there are several available that can save all images on a web page.  There's [one here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-all-images-webextension/) for Mozilla Firefox. I have no affiliation with the plugin creator or Mozilla, and haven't used it so I can't vouch for it. Use it at your own risk. Maybe check the reviews before installing.

Just a word of caution though, it may not be legal to just copy and reuse images you found on a web page. Nearly all images on the web are copyright.